# NVIDIA drivers work in recovery mode but not with GDM

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, 22.04

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 with the 5.15.0-47 kernel.
Today I decided to install nvidia drivers from www.nvidia.com, which worked well on the same laptop when it was on Ubuntu 20.04.

I cannot boot anymore. It freezes on the Ubuntu logo screen.

- Ctrl + Alt + F1: black screen
- Ctrl + Alt + F2 - 9: black screen with blinking cursor

I can boot with the 5.15.0-46 kernel with no problem.
I can also boot in recovery mode and run stuff on my GPU just fine (I tried PyTorch).

I uninstalled the driver and purged every nvidia stuff on my system before reinstalling the drivers with *apt get install nvidia-driver-515*. Same result.

I'm stuck because I cannot find any major error in the logs and the recovery mode works well. What do you suggest?

The three issues I've found:

- ucsi_cgg 1-0008: i2c_transfer failed -110
- ucsi_ccg 1-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110
- nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or key missing - tainting kernel

Graphic card: Geforce GTX 1660 Ti.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in UEFI and try again.

Comment: Secure Boot disabled in the BIOS. Same problem.